# How can I get a SVN diff from the point a branch was started to HEAD?

Tags: svn

I'd like to see what changes have occurred on a branch, but I'm not sure how. I'd imagine I'd need to find the first revision of the branch and use that?

Googling has not helped me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roughly

```
svn log --diff --stop-on-copy https://subversion/.../branches/BR-2-7-3
```

Comment: `svn log  --stop-on-copy -l1 -r1:HEAD` will show the branchpoint revision only, which you can then pass to `svn diff` for the whole branch diff in 1.

Comment: You can just use `svn log --diff --stop-on-copy` (without branch) if you already have the branch checked out

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, it is a matter of doing a diff between the revision number of when the branch was created and the revision number of the version you wish to compare it to (in this case it is probably the latest commit on the branch)

You will need to perform this in two steps:

1) Find the revision number of when the branch was created and the revision number of the latest commit

```
svn log --stop-on-copy <branch location eg. "https://subversion/.../branches/BR-2-7-3">
```

This will show you a log of all the commits on the branch with the latest one at the top (in the form rYYYY) and the start of the branch at the bottom (in the form rXXXX). Remember the revision number of both of those commits (XXXX and YYYY)

2) Do a diff between those two revisions

```
svn diff -rXXXX:YYYY <branch location eg. "https://subversion/.../branches/BR-2-7-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using Eclipse! but if you are, you can switch to SVN Repository Exploring- right click on the branch you want and then click show history. There it will tell you what changed and by who.

Answer (score 0):

`svn log` now has argument  `--diff` to generate diff output:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy --diff path/to/branch
```

Pipe to `colordiff` and `less -R` for git-like output.